# RXJS BehaviorSubject.next() doesn't call subscribers

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service with the following

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  private mySubject = new BehaviorSubject({});
  public currentData = this.mySubject.asObservable();

  updateData(data: any) {
     this.mySubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

I have a component that is subscribed to the `Observable` with the 
following:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.currentData.subscribe(data => /* some logic here */);
  }  
}
```

I have another component that calls the `updateData` method of the service.

```
export class AnotherComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  onClick(data) {
    this.myService.updateData(data);
  }
}
```

I am expecting that the `.subscribe` defined in `MyComponent` would get called on the `this.myService.updateData` call within `AnotherComponent.onClick`, but it does not. I can confirm that the Observable does has a subscriber attached to it, as you would expect given the code.

Comment: Use this: `private mySubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);`

Comment: How do you know `currentData` does have observers as you exepect?

Comment: @martin via the debugger and inspecting which closures are attached to the _subscribe property.

Comment: Are you sure that you provided the service once? I mean is it just provided using `provideIn: 'root'`

Comment: @Neeko you can check `mySubject.observers.length`

Comment: Can you check if components use the same instance of MyService?

Comment: @NimaHakimi yes, I am only providing the service once.

Answer (score 0):

the closure defined in `this.myService.currentData.subscribe(data => /* some logic here */);` was throwing an uncaught exception, which would prevent this closure from being called again in subsequent `.next()` calls. Fixing the source of the exception (or using a `try...catch`) resolved the issue.